# C# BitConverter в Python

Tags: c#, python, byte, bytearray

C#:

```
byte[] b_array; //0x1314FFAAF810
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { b_array[i*2], b_array[i*2+1] };
Int16 toint = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 0);
```

Python:

```
b_array = bytearray([0x1314FFAAF810])
```

Вопрос: как вот 13,14,FF... из массива конвертировать в int16 в Python

Comment: так то `[0x1314FFAAF810]` хватит на 3 штуки `Int16`, разве нет??

Comment: @Alias да. Верно.

Comment: ввод у вас неверный показан (bytearray ожидает байты (`0<=b<256`)). Что у вас на входе? Строка с шестнадцатеричными цифрами (текст `type('1314FFAAF810') == str`) или у вас именно байты на входе: `type(b'\x13\x14\xff\xaa\xf8\x10') == bytes`?

Answer (score 1):

В Python для этих целей надо использовать модуль [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html).

```
import struct
from binascii import unhexlify

s = '1314FFAAF810'
size = 2  # int16 (код 'h' для unpack)

bs = unhexlify(s)  # 1314FFAAF810 -- > b'\x13\x14\xff\xaa\xf8\x10'

print(*struct.unpack(len(bs) // size * 'h', bs))  # --> 5139 -21761 4344
```

Comment: я бы сказал можно использовать. Не обессудьте, но вариант с int тоже рабочий, хотя несколько кишкообразнее он получается

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov, зачем выполнять столько ручной работы, когда есть стандартная библиотека? Сколько усилий придется потратить для того, чтобы использовать этот код для другого типа данных? Не говоря уже о магических байтах для решения вопроса знаковости. P.S. Я не спорю, что он рабочий, и не говорю, что он плохой, просто считаю вариант с использованием библиотеки языка наиболее предпочтительным. Минус ставил не я.

Comment: я с вам согласен, велосипеды не нужны, но раз уж изобрел так изобрел... Мне ваше решение разумеется нравится, оно чистое, понятное. И я вам поставил плюс.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас на входе 6 байт и вы хотите интерпретировать их как 16+-битовые целые числа со знаком с системным порядком байтов (`signed short`):

```py
>>> import array
>>> a = array.array('h')
>>> a.frombytes(b'\x13\x14\xff\xaa\xf8\x10')
>>> a
array('h', [5139, -21761, 4344])
```

Если на входе hex-строка, то легко можно соответствующие байты получить:

```py
>>> bytes.fromhex('1314FFAAF810')
b'\x13\x14\xff\xaa\xf8\x10'
```

Если на входе Python int:

```py
>>> n = 0x1314FFAAF810 
>>> n.to_bytes((n.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big')
b'\x13\x14\xff\xaa\xf8\x10'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t1 = '0x1314FFAAF810'
t2 = int(t1, 16)
```

только предупреждаю, Python не имеет типа Int16, Вы сразу получите целое число таким, как оно есть

Comment: Мне надо не все число разом а разбить по отдельным  байтам Т.е получатеся что надо toint = int(bytes,16)?

Comment: программа выведет совсем не то, что пользователь хочет.

Comment: так как в написано в t1 он лежит в SQL Server. Его нужно разбить по байтам: 1314 FFAA F810 и преобразовать в int16

Comment: простите, Вы ничего не говорили за за sql... тогда нужно использовыать срез и список... def myfunc(info):
   tmp_list = []
   while len(info) > 0:
      tmp_list.append(int(info[:4],16))
      info = info[4:]
   return tmp_list

t1 = '1314FFAAF810'
t2 = myfunc(t1)

Answer (score 0):

### C# реализация на базе вашего примера

```
public static byte[] StrToByteArray(string str)
{
    Dictionary<string, byte> hexindex = new Dictionary<string, byte>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++)
        hexindex.Add(i.ToString("X2"), (byte)i);

    List<byte> hexres = new List<byte>();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i += 2)
        hexres.Add(hexindex[str.Substring(i, 2)]);

    return hexres.ToArray();
}
public static void Main()
{
    byte[] b_array = StrToByteArray("1314FFAAF810");
    for (int i = 0; i < b_array.Length / 2; ++i)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[] { b_array[i * 2], b_array[i * 2 + 1] };
        Int16 toint = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 0);
        Console.WriteLine(toint + " ");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Программа будет иметь следующий вывод

> 5139, -21761, 4344

Можем заметить, что BitConverter при преобразовании hex числа `0x1314` поменял местами байты при преобразовании, так как `0x1413 = 5139`

### Python реализация

Вот код на Python, который делает тоже самое

```
t1 = '0x1314FFAAF810'

step = 4
i = 2
while i < len(t1) :
    lows = t1[i : i + 2]
    bigs = t1[i + 2 : i + 4]
    x = int(bigs + lows, 16)
    if x > 0x7FFF:
        x = -(0xFFFF - x + 1)
    print x
    i = i + step
```

Программа будет иметь идентичный вывод выводу C#

> 5139, -21761, 4344

Здесь мы извлекаем из строки последовательно байты и перед преобразованием меняем их местами, чтобы сохранить поведение C#.

Пример работы скрипта: https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/cfadab0f-1f4f-4730-a03f-2474bc29be1d/?i=true

Comment: за что минус? Поясните пжлста.

Comment: "минусовщик" всем поставил минус и ушел по английски... видимо ушел на английский stackoverflow, так как на русском думаю русские сидят и поясняют, за что минус.